# How would I create a function to separate and average rows of this data

Tags: r, function, split, average

I'm new to R and have a large data frame with which I'd like to separate the data by a single letter in the column name, and then append a column at the end containing the average of the row. The data looks as follows:

```
    V1          V2  V3             V4        V5       V6       V7       V8       V9      V10      
1          gene_id gene_symbol Chr        Biotype     L001P    L003P    L004P    L005P    L008P   
2  ENSG00000000003      TSPAN6   X protein_coding   31.8003  67.3098   63.033    63.83  38.6941  
3  ENSG00000000005        TNMD   X protein_coding 0.0372353  2.28841 0.032932        0 0.358512        
4  ENSG00000000419        DPM1  20 protein_coding   17.5575  43.7474  21.0119  22.9765  26.3166  
5  ENSG00000000457       SCYL3   1 protein_coding   2.68196   3.7079  3.14505  3.82323  3.32028  
6  ENSG00000000460    C1orf112   1 protein_coding  0.532179  2.46598  1.11985 0.584227  1.20095
```

There are around 70 columns and 13 rows, you can only see the columns with the "P" ending (V6:V10), however 39 columns down the data frame they end in "t". I was wondering how I'd separate these two "t" and "p", and then mean the rows.

I've tried `apply`, `lapply`, `grep` and `split` but still cant seem to separate them. Whenever I have tried to apply a mean it returns NA values across the board, now sure where to go from here.

Comment: It looks like you imported the data without headers, so the column names are `V1, V2, ...` instead of `gene_id, ...`. If you fix this you can select columns by number using `which(stringr::str_detect(names(yourdata), "P$"))` for the `P` columns for example.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have read the data incorrectly (maybe selected `header = FALSE` while importing).It looks like your first row should be your header and your actual data starts from row 2 onwards.

```
names(df) <- df[1, ] #Give 1st row as column names
df  <- df[-1, ]      #Delete 1st row
```

Once, we have that let's find out column which end with `"t"` or `"P"`

```
cols <- grep("P$|t$", names(df))
```

Since we had messed up the 1st row previously the type of columns have changed and we need to convert `cols` to numeric

```
df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], as.numeric)
```

Now, we can take `mean` of these rows using `rowMeans`

```
df$Mean <- rowMeans(df[cols], na.rm = TRUE)
```

I am not clear if you want to calculate the `mean` of columns ending with `"P"` and `"t"` together or separately. The above calculates it together. If you want to calculate them separately you can do

```
p_cols <- grep("P$", names(df))
t_cols <- grep("t$", names(df))
df[c(p_cols, t_cols)] <- lapply(df[c(p_cols, t_cols)], as.numeric)
df$P_Mean <- rowMeans(df[p_cols], na.rm = TRUE)
df$T_Mean <- rowMeans(df[t_cols], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity, I'd like the there to be a mean for each individual row (for each gene). Also when using `cols <- grep("P$|t$", names(df))` it shows the integer as empty. What should I do about this

Comment: @NewToR did you do the first part? Changing column names and deleting the 1st row? `names(df) <- df[1, ] ;df  <- df[-1, ]` ? and after doing that do you see column names ending with `P` or `t` ?

Comment: Yes I have done both `names(df) <- df[1, ]` and `df  <- df[-1, ]`. However, once `names(df) <- df[1, ]` is perfomed the V1, V2 etc are replaced by the number of different values in these columns (Eg over the chromosome column it shows 23). If I were to erase these V1, V2 headings should I `names(df) <- NULL`?

Comment: @NewToR Maybe you have factor columns in your data. Let's start from beginning. First convert all the data to character.  . `df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)` Then apply names `names(df) <- df[1, ]` and then remove the row `df  <- df[-1, ] `. What is `names(df)` now? and check `cols` as well `cols <- grep("P$|t$", names(df))`

Comment: Ah yes that seems to have fixed the problem integer problem. However I need the P columns and the T columns to be separated into their own data frames so I can mean the rows separately

Comment: If you want to mean them separately, you can try the last part in the answer where I have separated `p_cols` and `t_cols` and taken `mean` of those columns separately.

Answer (score 1):

here a `data.table` approach:

As you don't provide any reproducible example data, I had to fabricate one:

```
# load library

library(data.table)

# create data.table as the column binding of some letters and some numbers

dt <- cbind(data.table(x = LETTERS[1:5]), 
            as.data.table(matrix(sample(1:30, 30, FALSE), 
                                 nrow = 5)))

# the names aren't right, so we need to fix them according to your requirement:

names(dt) <- c("x", "1T", "2T", "3T", "1P", "2P", "3P")
```

Now the working part: We will create a column (that's what `:=` is for) that has the mean applied (that's the `apply` and `mean` functions) on some columns (that's the `.SD`) that we need to define (that's the `.SDcols` part).
But that definition is dyamic, depending on the last letter of the column name, so we use `grep`:

```
dt[, averageTs := apply(.SD, 1, mean), .SDcols = grep("T$", names(dt))]
```

In here we're looking for a T at the end of the string, and the vector we'll be searching is that of the `names` of the data.table itself.

Doing it for the Ps is just the same command, of course replacing Ts for Ps.

```
dt[, averagePs := apply(.SD, 1, mean), .SDcols = grep("P$", names(dt))]
```